# Group query result data by column and set default values for all missing columns in each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, default-value

I've created a method what creates a list of items but not every value is filled. I've tried several ways but none of them fixed the issue. I've played with the if else statements but it didn't fixed the result. I still get less values then I expect. Can someone give me a hint or rewrite my method, so I can go back to my project.

Method:

```
public function getDataListItems(int $category, array $list) 
{
    global $dbh;

    $query = 'SELECT data.value, data.uid, fields.name 
              FROM data 
                JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
              WHERE fields.category_id = "' . trim($category) . 
            '" ORDER BY uid';

    $sql = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    $values = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $data = '';
    $items = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        foreach ($list as $key) {
            if(!empty($data)){
                if($data == $value['uid']) {
                    if($key == $value['name']) {
                        $item = [
                            $value['name'] => $value['value'],
                            'uid' => $value['uid'],
                        ];
                    }else{
                        $item = [
                            $key => '',
                            'uid' => $value['uid'],
                        ];          
                    }
                    $items[$value['uid']] = array_merge($items[$value['uid']], $item);
                }else{
                    if($key == $value['name']) {
                        $items[$value['uid']] = [
                            $value['name'] => $value['value'],
                            'uid' => $value['uid'],
                        ];  
                    }else{
                        $items[$value['uid']] = [
                            $key => '',
                            'uid' => $value['uid'],
                        ];          
                    }       
                }
            }else{
                if($key == $value['name']) {
                    $items[$value['uid']] = [
                        $value['name'] => $value['value'],
                        'uid' => $value['uid'],
                    ];  
                }else{
                    $items[$value['uid']] = [
                        $key => '',
                        'uid' => $value['uid'],
                    ];          
                }       
            }
            $data = $value['uid'];
        }
    }
    return $items;  
}
```

In `$list` you'll find:

```
array(3) {
  ["Voornaam"]=> string(8) "Voornaam"
  ["Achternaam"]=> string(10) "Achternaam"
  ["Initialen"]=> string(9) "Initialen"
}
```

in `$values` you'll find:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(7) "Bettina"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245f"
    ["name"]=> string(8) "Voornaam"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(3) "Les"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245f"
    ["name"]=> string(10) "Achternaam"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(6) "Simone"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245g"
    ["name"]=> string(8) "Voornaam"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(4) "Yül"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245l"
    ["name"]=> string(10) "Achternaam"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(6) "Joshua"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245s"
    ["name"]=> string(8) "Voornaam"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(3) "Mas"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245s"
    ["name"]=> string(10) "Achternaam"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=> string(5) "Hello"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"
    ["name"]=> string(10) "Achternaam"
  }
}
```

What I get in the return:

```
["7d1f4f8e906245f"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245f"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(3) "Les"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
["7d1f4f8e906245g"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(6) "Simone"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245g"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
["7d1f4f8e906245l"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245l"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(4) "Yül"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
  ["7d1f4f8e906245s"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245s"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(3) "Mas"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
  ["gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(5) "Hello"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
}
```

What I expect result array:

```
    ["7d1f4f8e906245f"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) "Bettina"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245f"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(3) "Les"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
["7d1f4f8e906245g"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(6) "Simone"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245g"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
["7d1f4f8e906245l"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245l"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(4) "Yül"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
  ["7d1f4f8e906245s"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) "Joshua"
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "7d1f4f8e906245s"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(3) "Mas"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
  ["gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Voornaam"]=> string(0) ""
    ["uid"]=> string(15) "gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn"
    ["Achternaam"]=> string(5) "Hello"
    ["Initialen"]=> string(0) ""
  }
}
```

You see that I miss some values in my return list.

Comment: Please always present your array data as `var_export()` text instead of `print_r()` or `var_dump()` text -- this help volunteers to instantly work with your data.  Why are you bothering to call `trim()` on an integer type value?  You should parameterize and then write `$sql->execute($category);`  `fetchAll()` should not be used if you are going to iterate the result set in the same "layer" <-- this is from the php docs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i've change it but this doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group the results based on the `uid` values and set some default values -- this can be done without so many conditions.  Use `isset()` to determine if the `uid` is being encountered for the first time.  If so, set the defaults.  Then overwrite the defaults with every subsequent encounter for that same `uid`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QNfti))

```
$values = [
    ['value' => 'Bettina', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245f', 'name' => 'Voornaam'],
    ['value' => 'Les', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245f', 'name' =>  'Achternaam'],
    ['value' => 'Simone', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245g', 'name' => 'Voornaam'],
    ['value' => 'Yül', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245l', 'name' =>  'Achternaam'],
    ['value' => 'Joshua', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245s', 'name' => 'Voornaam'],
    ['value' => 'Mas', 'uid' =>  '7d1f4f8e906245s', 'name' =>  'Achternaam'],
    ['value' => 'Hello', 'uid' =>  'gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn', 'name' =>  'Achternaam'],
];

$list = ['Voornaam', 'Achternaam', 'Initialen'];

foreach ($values as $row) {
    if (!isset($items[$row['uid']])) {
        $items[$row['uid']] = array_fill_keys($list, '');  // if it needs to dynamically generated
        $items[$row['uid']]['uid'] = $row['uid'];
    }
    $items[$row['uid']][$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}

var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '7d1f4f8e906245f' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Bettina',
    'Achternaam' => 'Les',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245f',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245g' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Simone',
    'Achternaam' => '',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245g',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245l' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => '',
    'Achternaam' => 'Yül',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245l',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245s' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Joshua',
    'Achternaam' => 'Mas',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245s',
  ),
  'gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => '',
    'Achternaam' => 'Hello',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => 'gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn',
  ),
)
```

Truth be told, if this was my application, I would be writing a pivot query and doing all of this in sql so that the `fetchAll()` value could be instantly returned.

Answer (score 1):

You used the `uid` as the key to the new array. But you have more than one occurance in the original array of the same `uid`

This one `7d1f4f8e906245f` and this one `7d1f4f8e906245s` occur twice.

Therefore your loop will overwrite the first occurance you create in the result with the second.

You will have to rethink what you want to use as a key to your new array. Basically your `uid` (UniqueId) is not unique in this case

Comment: The UID is to combine the values who are together. Can you give me a example to fix tihs?

Comment: So do you want 2 sub arrays for the duplicate uid's?

Comment: I want in my return to see all information combine in one array if the uid is the same

Comment: Please would you show an example of how you want to see the result array please. Add a sample to your question

Answer (score 0):

A completely separate/alternative solution (which I recommend if your application doesn't need to be fully dynamic) is to execute all of the processing logic at the earliest point -- in sql.

Using a pivot will allow you to swiftly go from query to returned result set in a snap.

Query: ([db-fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2oPY9iuD2pzLHQyUvcHuD1/0))

```
SELECT 
    MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Voornaam', data.value, '')) AS Voornaam,
    data.uid,
    MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Achternaam', data.value, '')) AS Achternaam,
    MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Initialen', data.value, '')) AS Initialen
FROM data 
JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
WHERE fields.category_id = 1
GROUP BY data.uid ASC
```

Result Set:

```
| Voornaam | Achternaam | Initialen | uid             |
| -------- | ---------- | --------- | --------------- |
| Bettina  | Les        |           | 7d1f4f8e906245f |
| Simone   |            |           | 7d1f4f8e906245g |
|          | Yül        |           | 7d1f4f8e906245l |
| Joshua   | Mas        |           | 7d1f4f8e906245s |
|          | Hello      |           | gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn |
```

Code:

```
public function getDataListItems(int $category, array $list) 
{
    global $dbh;

    $query = "SELECT 
                  MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Voornaam', data.value, '')) AS Voornaam,
                  data.uid,
                  MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Achternaam', data.value, '')) AS Achternaam,
                  MAX(IF(fields.name = 'Initialen', data.value, '')) AS Initialen
              FROM data 
              JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id 
              WHERE fields.category_id = ?
              GROUP BY data.uid ASC";
    $sql = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute($category);
    return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  // this will be an indexed array of associative arrays
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way. But it need to be dynamic.